# pdftools package failing to parse characters

Tags: r, pdf

I am using the pdftools to parse pdfs and have come across a pdf it is failing to accurately parse (it is working on other PDFs so I don't think its related to the code).

The PDF can be found here: https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/st_10113_2007_init_en.pdf

My code is:

```
EU_text_2007 <- pdf_text("2007_CA_Strategy.pdf") %>% 
  readr::read_lines() %>% 
  str_squish()
```

Returns

[1] "                                                                                               (''&#!\n                     %$+!&,!-%&!0+%'2-3!(4(-)!7'2-'+*9!+,2!-!'+-!=-2'%+24$(.!\n!\n!\n#/!      #%'2,&@0'(,%)!%$+!&,!-%&!0+%'2-3!(4(-!\n!\n345678&!'):8!;8)!8!%456$7:4)3*& !678 :6:*5!*@!(7:5(:5(!-$7*B4!85 !'):8!6*

```
EU_text_2007_long <- paste(EU_text_2007, collapse = ' ')

EU_text_2007_long <- EU_text_2007_long %>% 
  as.data.frame() 

colnames(EU_text_2007_long) <- c('Text')

EU_text_2007_long <- EU_text_2007_long %>%
  mutate(Year = 2007) %>% 
  mutate(Text = as.character(Text))


EU_text_2007_tokens <- EU_text_2007_long %>% 
  unnest_tokens(tokens, Text, token = "words")
```

When tokenised the data looks something like this:

Year |tokens

1   2007    0
1.1 2007    2
1.2 2007    3
1.3 2007    4
1.4 2007    7'2
1.5 2007    9
1.6 2007    2
1.7 2007    2
1.8 2007    24
1.9 2007    2

I have tried removing the first page in case the watermark was causing an issue but this has not been successful.

Could someone see if they also are unable to parse this document, or if not have any suggestions as to why this may be happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem that you will occaisionally encounter with pdf text extraction. The pdf format can handle several different font types, and it handles them in different ways. In the case of your document, the font of the text in question is a type0 (PostScript) font called CAL invisible TT.

Often, the page description program in the pdf will output strings in low-value, non-ascii bytes. These are then looked up in the font's encoding dictionary and the appropriate glyph is pulled from the font description program, which is embedded in the file. Your font doesn't have an Encoding dictionary - it is labelled as Identity-H. Usually that means it will have a ToUnicode entry instead, and indeed yours does - but it is effectively empty.

As sometimes happens, in your case the glyphs in the font description program are not mapped to their proper Ascii value and are just mapped directly to those low byte values (for example, an A glyph might be mapped to 0x01 rather than its usual value of 0x41).

In the case of this particular document, this is actually done on purpose to prevent copy / pasting.

So why does the text look OK on the page?

It's because the font description program gets the message to print the glyph 0x01, but the picture it draws is of a letter A. At no point does the pdf itself "know" the ascii value of what it's printing. Neither does any other program, except perhaps an OCR program.

You can prove this is the case by trying to copy and paste the text. It doesn't work, because the glyphs displayed do not have an accurate underlying ascii representation.

Without some serious reverse engineering, you can't copy and paste from this particular document, and neither can any pdf text extraction tools. I'm not saying it's impossible, but it is very unlikely to be the kind of trivial problem that can be solved via Stack Overflow.

The best option is likely to be OCR.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is totally right and pretty clear in the diagnosis of the problem (and offers an impressive amount of background information). And I agree, that  Optical character recognition (OCR) is probably the best way forward.

And it shouldn't be a big problem in this case either, as the PDF does contain a high quality image of the text (even though the underlying text data is unusable).

`pdftools` luckily already contains a well working function to solve this problem then and it should retrieve the (majority of) the text in this document correctly:

```
text <- pdftools::pdf_ocr_text("https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/st_10113_2007_init_en.pdf", pages = 1)
#> Converting page 1 to st_10113_2007_init_en_1.png... done!
text[1]
#> [1] "COUNCIL OF Brussels, 31 May 2007\nTHE EUROPEAN UNION\n10113/07\nLIMITE\nPESC 655\nCOEST 179\nNOTE\nfrom: The Permanent Representatives Committee\ndated: 31 May 2007\nto: Council\nSubject : The EU and Central Asia: Strategy for a New Partnership\n1. |The Permanent Representatives Committee has endorsed at its meeting on 30 May 2007\nStrategy for a New Partnership with Central Asia as set out in Annex.\n2. The Council (General Affairs and External Relations) is invited to reach an agreement on the\ntext as set out in Annex with the view to its submission to the European Council.\n10113/07 AA/gso l\nDGE VI LIMITE EN\n"
```

(Set `pages = NULL` to get the entire document.)

Comment: I agree that OCR is the way forward here (and I have upvoted your answer for a clear demo of how to do this easily). You say that you disagree with my saying that this is a difficult problem to solve, but  I think it was pretty clear in my answer that it is reverse engineering the _text encoding_ that is very difficult, not extracting the text, so by showing how to do OCR, you are not at all disagreeing with what I said.

Comment: You are right. I just re-read your answer (which I already upvoted for the diagnosis and interesting technical info) and changed mine. I think mine is basically an addition to your suggestion.

Comment: thanks - though I think your answer might be more helpful to the OP!